# REQUEST_TIMEOUT when trying to start business network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

When I try to start my business network app on composer v1.1 I get a timeout after 5 minutes with the following message:

> 2018-03-31 12:54:39.183 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 4c3
>   launchAndWaitForRegister failed: timeout expired while starting
>   chaincode
>   sre-frontend-app:0.0.1(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com,tx:ab15fb53ed8e1de99ad7253ffa2ab4b68bd787b8a9561c9b422bc203e14fc048)

There is also another error in the logs:

> 2018-03-31 12:54:39.183 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> ERRO 4c5
>   [composerchannel][ab15fb53] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" ,
>   error: timeout expired while starting chaincode
>   sre-frontend-app:0.0.1(networkid:dev,peerid:peer0.org1.example.com,tx:ab15fb53ed8e1de99ad7253ffa2ab4b68bd787b8a9561c9b422bc203e14fc048)

Any idea what might be happening? I have tried changing localhost to 0.0.0.0 when building the PeerAdmin card and even tried changing the listening address of fabric-ca to localhost based on reading other's solutions but these changes did not work for me.

Any other suggestions?? Do I need to extend the timeouts - and how I would do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Nevermind - this turned out to be due to a JS typo in my code. Anyone else who sees a similar issue - please check the logs: e.g. docker logs -f dev-peer0.org1.example.com-sre-frontend-app-0.0.1 when this container is created and see the errors within. Hope that helps.